# Cypher query for Intersection of Complex lists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need help with a query, in which I want to filter the items from a json object matching two fields of the object (id, type), something like this,

```
match (o:Item) where o.id="18" and o.type="test" 
with [{id: '16', type: 'p1', value: 2}, {id: '3', type: 'p2', value: 1}, {id: '54', type: 'p1', value: 3}, {id: '16', type: 'p1', value: 5}, {id: '1143', type: 'p1', value: 4}, {id: '18', type: 'test', value: 4}] as p_list, o
unwind p_list as p_item
with distinct o, p_item
match (o) where not o.id = p_item.id and not o.type = p_item.type
return o
```

- Expected Result: **null**, as the p_list contains the item with id **18** and type **test**.
- Actual Result: 5 rows, because of the cross multiplication of node with the list, inferring from here that it is filtering the p_list instead of filtering the node (o).

> I want the intersection of the node (o) with the list giving the
>   result left from node(o) rows.

Can any help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You should not even bother to search the DB if your desired `id` and `type` combination are in `p_list`.

This should work (and efficiently avoid searching if not necessary):

```
WITH
  [{id: '16', type: 'p1', value: 2}, {id: '3', type: 'p2', value: 1}, {id: '54', type: 'p1', value: 3}, {id: '16', type: 'p1', value: 5}, {id: '1143', type: 'p1', value: 4}, {id: '18', type: 'test', value: 4}] as p_list,
  '18' AS id,
  'test' AS type
WHERE NONE(p IN p_list WHERE p.id = id AND p.type = type)
MATCH (o:Item) where o.id = id and o.type = type 
RETURN o
```

If the `WHERE` test fails, then the subsequent `MATCH` is not even attempted.

For easy reuse of this query, you can omit the `WITH` clause and pass `p_list`, `id`, and `type` as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

Comment: I want to filter the graph result from the list provided. I dont want any of the list items to appear in my result. All the other ids should come from the graph except the items from p_list.

Comment: I understand that. But you can figure out *before you even perform a `MATCH`* that the `p_list` makes the `MATCH` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I received help from @maxdemarzi from neo4j community.
His solution,

```
WITH [{id: '16', type: 'p1', value: 2}, {id: '3', type: 'p2', value: 1}, {id: 
'54', type: 'p1', value: 3}, {id: '16', type: 'p1', value: 5}, {id: '1143', 
type: 'p1', value: 4}, {id: '18', type: 'test', value: 4}] AS p_list
OPTIONAL MATCH (o:Item) 
WHERE o.id="18" AND o.type="test" 
WITH o, p_list
WHERE NOT o.id IN [x IN p_list WHERE x.type = o.type | x.id]
RETURN o
```

> `WHERE NOT o.id IN [x IN p_list WHERE x.type = o.type | x.id]` - this is the key for filtering complex objects.